# What is the use of views in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view

Why do i need to create a view when i can simply write a select query?
for e.g.

```
/
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testview AS SELECT empno,ename,sal FROM emp;
/
```

Instead of this why can't i write a simple select query such as

```
/
SELECT empno,ename,sal FROM emp;
/
```

What is the actual use of views.In which scenario views are used?

Comment: First stop for questions like this is Oracle Database Concepts https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/schemaob.htm#CNCPT311 which is part of the documentation (and required reading for everyone working with Oracle). Then come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle views offer some compelling benefits. These include:

- Commonality of code being used. Since a view is based on one common set of SQL, this means that when it is called it's less likely to require parsing. This is because the basic underlying SQL that is called is always the same. However, since you can add additional where clauses when calling a view, you still need to use bind variables. Additional where clauses without a bind variable can still cause a hard parse!
- Security. Views have long been used to hide the tables that actually contain the data you are querying. Also, views can be used to restrict the columns that a given user has access to. Using views for security on less complex databases is probably not a bad thing. As databases become more complex, this solution becomes harder to scale and other solutions will be needed.
- Predicate pushing. Oracle supports pushing of predicates into a given view.
- Performance. They should be used instead of a table for a faster execution.

Comment: Regarding Performance I do not agree. Why should a view be faster than a regular select? The only reason could be: When you select a view then the Select statement is always the same and Oracle can re-use existing execution plans or any data stored in result cache. However, this also applies when you run the same regular select statements several times. So no difference between a view and a regular select.

Answer (score 0):

One more use of views is that you can store complex queries behind them. If you for instance need to query data that comes from several tables, it's easier to create a view one time, so that the next time you need that data, you don't have to write a query to join those tables up again. Instead, you can just query the view.

Views are by the way not a Oracle thing, they are available in many (if not all) RDBM systems.